# Get form value to use as paperclip filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Is it possible to get form field value and use it as paperclip attachment filename?

`PiecePhoto` model:

```
belongs_to :piece

has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => {
        :slider => "940x420#",
        :single => "540>",
        :thumb => "60x60#",
        :medium => "140x140#",
        :original => "1024x1024>"
    }, 
    :path => ":attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
    :url => ":attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => 'monavala',
    :s3_credentials =>"#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml"

validates_presence_of :image
before_post_process :parameterize_file_name

def parameterize_file_name
    extension = File.extname(image_file_name).gsub(/^\.+/, '')
    filename = File.basename(image_file_name, ".#{extension}").parameterize
    self.image.instance_write(:file_name, "#{filename}.#{extension}")
end
```

In `filename = File.basename(image_file_name, ".#{extension}").parameterize` i would like instead of `image_file_name` to get value from form field.

**Edit:**

Model is nested

```
Piece
    has_many :piece_photos
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :piece_photos

PiecePhotos
    belongs_to :piece
    has_attached_file :image
```

I understand that getting form value inside model breaks MVC pattern. Is there another way?

**Edit2:**

Tried to be strict here, but I think I'll have to explain a little more.

Form is nested, I have `Collection` form that `:has_many` `Pieces` that `:has_many` `PiecePhotos`.

Fields can be added for `Pieces` and for each `Piece` you can add `PiecePhotos`.

I would like that file name for `PiecePhotos` to be same as `Piece` name + some unique string or id.

So everything has to be done in one post. I don't want to upload piece photos first and later add them to piece.

Basically all I need is to get Piece name and use it as PiecePhoto file name.

Here is image how form looks now, it's still in development.

[image: Form Fields]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I've had the same problem this week and finally got it to work, so I figured I'd answer in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

Basically, Paperclip has the ability to use dynamic paths via Interpolations ([paperclip/interpolations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations)). To do this, at the top of your model you need to just add the interpolation code

PiecePhoto model:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :fixed_file_name do |attachment, style|
 attachment.instance.fixed_file_name
end
```

Now you can add `:fixed_file_name` or whatever you want to call it to the end of your url. Be sure to add the `:extension` or the file will be saved without one. It will automatically just use the same extension fro the file being uploaded, so there isn't any problems there.

```
:path => ":attachment/:id/:style/:fixed_file_name.:extension",
:url => ":attachment/:id/:style/:fixed_file_name.extension",
```

And then all you have left to do is define it. You can even just use the rails .parameterize. Just place `#{image_file_name}` or whatever the field name is, and add the `.parameterize`.

```
def fixed_file_name
 return "#{image_file_name.parameterize}"
end
```

I will admit I have ONLY tested this with Rails 4.2, since that is what I'm using, but I was able to get it working after much frustration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `params[:paramHere]` in your model, but it's not considered best practice, so when you do use it, first create a copy so you don't change anything.

```
params_copy = params.dup

....
filename = params[:attachment_name]
```

---

**Edit:**

The better alternative would be moving your filename code to the `PiecePhotoController`
with something like:

```
def create
  @piece_photo = PiecePhotos.new
  @piece_photo.file_attachment_name = params[:file_attachment_name]

  unless @piece_photo.save do
    #error-handling
  end
end
```

Or you can put the code into some other method if you are changing the `file_attachment_name` on an existing record, so you could have a method called `change_attachment_filename` or something.

---

**Edit2:**

But even the previous alternative shouldn't be required because paperclip is so simple that this should be sufficient:

This is your form (obviously it might have some more fields):

```
<% form_for :piece_photo, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :photo %>
<% end %>
```

Now all you have to do is create the `@piece_photo` record via `@piece_photo = PiecePhotos.create(params[:piece_photo])` and then you can display it like so:

```
<%= image_tag @piece_photo.photo.url %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag @piece_photo.photo.url(:thumb) %>
```

Have a look at this [blog post](http://jimneath.org/2008/04/17/paperclip-attaching-files-in-rails.html) or the official [paperclip github readme](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

Comment: I'm getting `undefined local variable or method `params'`.
I did not mentioned that model is nested.

Comment: Thanks for update. I have added more details to my problem.
I like approach with moving to another method but still there is problem that I have to upload PiecePhotos first and then associate them with Piece.